# React360 - Não é possível adicionar eventos de vídeo

Tags: javascript, react, javascript-eventos

Estou tentando entender o momento em que um vídeo foi concluído. Tentei usar os eventos de vídeo como a documentação diz, mas não consigo adicionar um ouvinte de eventos ao meu reprodutor de vídeo; quando o faço, recebo o erro "addeventlistener is not fuction". Espero que alguém saiba o que está acontecendo. Este é o meu código:

```js
VideoModule.createPlayer('myplayer');

VideoModule.play('myplayer', {
 source: { url: videoPath }, 
 stereo: '3DTB', 
 volume: 1,
 muted: false,
});

Environment.setBackgroundVideo('myplayer');

// the evet should be here
VideoModule.addEventListener('onVideoStatusChanged', (event: VideoStatusEvent) => {
    if (event.status === 'finished') {
        console.log('Video is finished');
    }
})

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso também foi um problema para mim, então eu corrigi a addListener documentação na solicitação de recebimento nº 758

https://github.com/facebook/react-360/pull/758

Bom para resolver seu problemas basta mudar a função "addEventListener" para "addListener", veja um exemplo correto:

```
player.addListener('onVideoStatusChanged', (event) => {
  if (event.status === 'finished') {
    console.log('Video is finished');
  }
})
```